# Matching strings that contain words with at least 2 spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to match strings that contain words with at least 2 spaces. How would I do that in regex?

```
$content = "one two three";
preg_match_all("~([\w]+(?:[\s]))+~", $content, $match); 
print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => one two ) [1] => Array ( [0] => two ) )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => one two three))
```

**P:S**

Please keep in mind that that the matching string has to contain AT LEAST 2 spaces, and the string must only contain words and spaces - it should not match if there are less than 2 spaces in the string, or if there are any other characters in the string that are not words or spaces.

Comment: Maybe a mere [`\S+\h+\S+\h+\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/dG6aT7/1) will do? See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BqMnzF) with `\s` (`\h` is used for demo only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?=(?:.*?\s){2})[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK0oS6/1)

Explanation:
`(?=(?:.*?\s){2})` Lookahead to check at least 2 spaces.
`[a-zA-Z ]` Matches only words and space.